# Are the Lowering and Raising Operators of QM the same as those of QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, conventions

We know that the lowering and raising operators in quantum mechanics are defined as

\begin{array}{l}
a =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X+i P) \\
a^{\dagger} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(X-i P),
\end{array}

respectively.

I was reading in [this book](https://books.google.de/books/about/Quantum_Theory_for_Mathematicians.html?id=bYJDAAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) page 257 about the different quantization schemes and he mentioned that the Wick-ordered quantization scheme is useful for quantum field theory and they are defined as:

\begin{aligned}
a &=X+i \alpha P \\
a^{\dagger} &=X-i \alpha P
\end{aligned}

He also mentioned that they differ by a constant from the first two raising and lowering operators and the commutator of $a$ and $a^\dagger$ is not $I$ but rather $2\alpha \hbar I$.

Does all of this mean that the raising and lowering operators of quantum mechanics are different than those of quantum field theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, normally one uses a convenient normalization for creation and annihilation operators. In QM there is usually only one frequency, *ω*, in your problem, so you incorporate it into the normalization of $a$ and $a^\dagger\equiv a^*$, (11.10), and it virtually disappears from the problem,
$$
D^2={\hbar \over m\omega}, \\
a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left ({X\over\sqrt{D}} +i {\sqrt{D}\over \hbar}P\right ),\\
a^*=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left ({X\over\sqrt{D}} -i {\sqrt{D}\over \hbar}P\right ),\leadsto \\
[a,a^*]=I,
$$
given $[X,P]=i\hbar I$.

In the case you are asking about, the many frequencies are not irrelevant, and become part of the normalization of each oscillator, so , as stated,
\begin{aligned}
a &=X+i \alpha P \\
a^{\dagger} &=X-i \alpha P
\end{aligned}
and, by a similar calculation,
$[a,a^*]=2\alpha \hbar I$, now. Presumably, he would proceed later down to fix $\alpha$, depending on the QFT oscillators he might be dealing with.

N.B. Some QFT books, but not all!, dealing with the infinity of commuting oscillators comprising QFT, normalize them as
$$[a_k,a^\dagger _p]=(2\pi)^3 \delta^3(\vec p -\vec k).    $$
But some also incorporate the energy of each in the normalization. Caveat lector!

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest me a good source on Weyl Quantization that might help me fully understand Stone-Von Neumann's Theorem?

Comment: Have you tried [Wikipedia](Stone-Von Neumann's Theorem) and [phase space formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation), and references therein? Our [booklet](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf) covers the waterfront pretty well, we thought.